# Home page not obeying post per page setting on the first page only

Tags: pagination, homepage, blog

I am working on a custom template for my office. I have a static front page and a static home page to display the blog posts. I am having a few minor issues and will have to create a few other questions as I fix each problem... Anyways, this problem is pretty interesting to me.

While in development, I have the post per page set to 3 (Settings > Reading). On the blog page (home.php) I do see my latest posts and that's fine. The problem is the home page is showing about 8 blog posts instead of the 3 that it is set to display. I am not doing anything custom with the query and just using the loop to display the post content.

The pagination works fine and functions as expected All paginated pages display only 3 posts and they are all the correct posts for each page. The only issue with this is that the home page first shows 8 posts instead of the 3 that is set in the settings.

Any help on this is much appreciated. I tried searching and could not find anyone having this issue so sorry if this is a duplicate post and hopefully I can get a push in the right direction.

I also checked with the Twenty Eleven theme and the same issue occurs. This is the template I copied some logic from.

I disabled all plugins and the issue still exists. The only plugins I was using were the WordPress SEO and WP Lightbox 2. Even after disabling them the issue still occurs.

If I increase the posts per page to 15 it shows 17... If I increase it to 6 I show 10. If I increase the number to 7 or 8 I show 11 posts. If I set it to 9 I show 12. 10 shows 13.... 12 shows 14... As you can see very frustrating. The only place where I change the query is on the front page but I doubt that is affecting the home page. I basically do a custom query on the front page to show only the last 6 sticky posts. I make sure the reset the query afterwards to be safe. Still have no clue about why this is happening. This has me going nuts!

I have provided my code below:

**home.php**

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Home Page (Blog Roll)
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="content" class="list-box">
        <?php
        /* Run the loop to output the page.
        * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
        * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
        */
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' );
        ?>
        <div class="page-nav">
            <?php if (get_next_posts_link()): ?>
            <span class="nav-button older-posts"><?php next_posts_link( '&laquo; Older posts'); ?></span>
            <?php 
            endif;
            if (get_previous_posts_link()): ?>
            <span class="nav-button newer-posts"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &raquo;' ); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**loop-single.php**

```
<?php
/**
* The loop that displays a single post.
*
* The loop displays the posts and the post content. See
* http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to understand it and
* http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to understand
* the tags used in it.
*
* This can be overridden in child themes with loop-single.php.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage EHRScopev2
*/
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-holder">
                <div class="box-frame">
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <em class="meta"><?php ehrscope_posted_on(); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class="total-comments"><?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span></em>
                        <?php
                        if (!is_single() && has_excerpt()):
                            the_excerpt();
                        else:
                            the_content(__('Continue reading', 'ehrscope') . ': <em>' . the_title('', '', false) . '</em>');
                        endif;
                        ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <?php
                        if (is_single()):
                            ehrscope_wp_link_pages();
                            $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                            ?>
                            <p class="entry-meta"><?php ehrscope_show_tags(); ?></p>
                            <?php if ($tags): ?>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle-related-posts" class="button"><?php _e('Show Related Posts', 'ehrscope'); ?></a>
                                <?php
                            endif;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (is_single()): ?>
            <div class="box" id="related-posts-cage">
                <div class="box-holder">
                    <div class="box-frame">
                        <div>
                            <?php if (is_single()): ?>
                                <?php
                                if ($tags):
                                    $tag_ids = array();
                                    foreach ($tags as $individual_tag) {
                                        $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                                    }
                                    $args = array(
                                        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                                        'posts_per_page' => 10, // Number of related posts to display.
                                        'caller_get_posts' => 1
                                    );
                                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                                    if ($my_query->have_posts()):
                                        ?>
                                        <h3><?php _e('Related Posts', 'ehrscope'); ?></h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php
                                            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                                                ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                    &nbsp;
                            <!--                                                <span class="related-posts-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span>-->
                                                </li>
                                                    <?php
                                            endwhile;
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                endif;
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        endif;
        comments_template('', true);
    endwhile;
else:
    ?>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-holder">
            <div class="box-frame">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h2><?php _e('No Results', 'ehrscope'); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'ehrscope'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Contents of `$wp_query`:

```
Array
(
    [page] => 0
    [pagename] => blog
    [error] => 
    [m] => 0
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [page_id] => 0
    [second] => 
    [minute] => 
    [hour] => 
    [day] => 0
    [monthnum] => 0
    [year] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [category_name] => 
    [tag] => 
    [cat] => 
    [tag_id] => 
    [author_name] => 
    [feed] => 
    [tb] => 
    [paged] => 0
    [comments_popup] => 
    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [preview] => 
    [s] => 
    [sentence] => 
    [fields] => 
    [category__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [cache_results] => 1
    [update_post_term_cache] => 1
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
    [post_type] => 
    [posts_per_page] => 3
    [nopaging] => 
    [comments_per_page] => 5
    [no_found_rows] => 
    [order] => DESC
)
```

Comment: Check how many posts you've set to be showing in Settings > Reading.

Comment: That is set to 3. That was the post per page setting I was referring to. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Could you try adding global $wp_query and include the results of print_r($wp_query->query_vars);

Comment: Updated post to show $wp_query contents. Thanks :)

Comment: how many 'sticky' posts do you have? http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

Comment: 6 but I only show 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a noobie mistake.

The sticky posts are added to the top of the page thus increasing the post count on the initial blogroll. I just had to remove the sticky posts from being sticky and that solved the issue.

I only use the sticky posts for the front page and I do not want them to be at the top of the home.php page.

Thanks for your help!

**Updated home.php**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page (Blog Roll)
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="content" class="list-box">
        <?php
        // Prevents sticky posts form always being at the top of the page. (still shows them in normal sort order)
        $queryObject = new WP_Query(array(
            'caller_get_posts' => '1',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
        ));        
        /* Run the loop to output the page.
        * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
        * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
        */
        get_template_part('loop', 'custom-query');
        ehrscope_posts_page_navigation();
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**loop-custom-query.php**

```
<?php
/**
* The loop that displays a single post.
*
* The loop displays the posts and the post content. See
* http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to understand it and
* http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to understand
* the tags used in it.
*
* This can be overridden in child themes with loop-single.php.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage EHRScopev2
*/
global $queryObject;
?>
<?php if ($queryObject->have_posts()) : while ($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-holder">
                <div class="box-frame">
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <em class="meta"><?php ehrscope_posted_on(); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class="total-comments"><?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span></em>
                        <?php
                        if (!is_single() && has_excerpt()):
                            the_excerpt();
                        else:
                            the_content(__('Continue reading', 'ehrscope') . ': <em>' . the_title('', '', false) . '</em>');
                        endif;
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        if (is_single()):
                            ehrscope_wp_link_pages();
                            $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                            ?>
                            <p class="entry-meta"><?php ehrscope_show_tags(); ?></p>
                            <?php if ($tags): ?>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle-related-posts" class="button"><?php _e('Show Related Posts', 'ehrscope'); ?></a>
                                <?php
                            endif;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (is_single()): ?>
            <div class="box" id="related-posts-cage">
                <div class="box-holder">
                    <div class="box-frame">
                        <div>
                            <?php if (is_single()): ?>
                                <?php
                                if ($tags):
                                    $tag_ids = array();
                                    foreach ($tags as $individual_tag) {
                                        $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                                    }
                                    $args = array(
                                        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                                        'posts_per_page' => 10, // Number of related posts to display.
                                        'caller_get_posts' => 1
                                    );
                                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                                    if ($my_query->have_posts()):
                                        ?>
                                        <h3><?php _e('Related Posts', 'ehrscope'); ?></h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php
                                            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                                                ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                    &nbsp;
                            <!--                                                <span class="related-posts-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span>-->
                                                </li>
                                                    <?php
                                            endwhile;
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                endif;
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        endif;
        comments_template('', true);
    endwhile;
else:
    ?>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-holder">
            <div class="box-frame">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h2><?php _e('No Results', 'ehrscope'); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'ehrscope'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a search through your theme's entire directory for the functions "is_home()" and "is_front_page()". The only thing I can think of is that there's a function written somewhere that makes the front page have 8 posts no matter how many posts are set per page on the rest of the blog.

Comment: I checked that and there is no such code. If I increase the posts per page to 15 it shows 17... If I increase it to 6 I show 10. If I increase the number to 7 or 8 I show 11 posts. If I set it to 9 I show 12. 10 shows 13.... 12 shows 14... As you can see very frustrating. The only place where I change the query is on the front page but I doubt that is affecting the home page. I basically do a custom query on the front page to show only the last 6 sticky posts. I make sure the reset the query afterwards to be safe. Still have no clue about why this is happening. Time to re-install maybe??